# Python, List Comprehension

Tags: python, split, anaconda

I'm really new to coding, so I hope I would get an answer I would more likely understand rather than its efficiency. I have a list comprised with strings that looks like this:

months = ['04', '04', '04', '04', '04', 
'05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '06', '07', '07, '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '1', '2', '3', '4']

I'm trying to split this list by value i.e. I would like the output to look like:

listed_months = [['04', '04', '04', '04', '04'], ['05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05'],......['04']]

Note: it's really crucial that although the last element still gets its own list even through it already has a list prior.

I have this as a starter:

```
months = ['04', '04', '05', '05', '05', '06', '07', 
'07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '1', '2', '3', '4']

listed_months = []
per_month = []
for i in range(0, len(months)):
    if months[i] == months[1+1]:
        per_month.append(months[i])
    elif months[i] != months[1+1]:
        per_month = []
        months = month[i+1]
        listed_months.append(per_month)
```

I get an issue that the index becomes out of range if I were to complete this loop since I forced the last value. 
I feel like I'm almost there but some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a built-in function for this, `itertools.groupby`, you would just use `[list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(months)]`. Doing this by hand, I'll note `months[1+1]` was supposed to probably be `months[i+1]`, in any case, it is easier to keep track of the *last* value seen instead of looking forward, and if it is equal, append to the temporary list, otherwise, append the temproary list to the final list, initialize a new empty list and append the value to that... then don't forget to check at the end if there is a temporary list to append.

Comment: `months[1+1]` should be `months[i+1]`

Comment: It is not obvious what behaviour is expected for a list like this `['1', '2', '1', '2', '3']` - should it result in `[['1'], ['2'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3']]` or `[['1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3']]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Will not work. OP wants last value alone.

Comment: @Tarik of course it will work. That's **exactly** how `itertools.groupby` works.

Comment: Should be `for i in range(0, len(months) - 1)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "Note: it's really crucial that although the last element still gets its own list even through it already has a list prior."

Comment: @Tarik I have. Why won't `itertools.groupby` work? **That's exactly what `itertools.groupby` will do**

Comment: Note, it would be really helpful if you gave **the complete expected output** just to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga He provided it. Just read. `listed_months = [['04', '04', '04', '04', '04'], ['05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05', '05'],......['04']]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Note the last element in the list: `['04']`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I meant "[i+1]" I just made that typo as I was copying the code over to the thread, but thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Tarik that is not a complete output. Note the `...` How should `'1', '2', '3',` be handled? It's not even clear to me if the OP meant to add a zero to the last string, or simply omitted it from their input (their code doesn't even attempt to handle that)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement this on your own, something like the following is the simplest I could find:

```
months = [
    '04', '04',
    '05', '05', '05',
    '06',
    '07', '07',
    '08',
    '09',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4', '4'
]

result = [[months[0]]]

for m in months[1:-1]:
    om = "%02d" % int(m)
    if om == result[-1][-1]:
        result[-1].append(om)
    else:
        result.append([om])
result.append(["%02d" % int(months[-1])])

print(result)
```

The above works on lists of length 2 or more. You can add processing for the trivial cases if you want/need them. The idea is that for every item from the second to the second to last, you append the item to the last sub-list in `result` if it is equal to the last item in that sub-list, or append a singleton list to `result` otherwise.

The last item is just added as a singleton list to the end of the result.

The output for this example would be:

```
[['04', '04'], ['05', '05', '05'], ['06'], ['07', '07'], ['08'], ['09'], ['02'], ['03'], ['04'], ['04']]
```